# When I enable ssl3-methods but disable ssl3 in OpenSSL

Tags: tls, openssl

I need to compile a tls scanning tool and I want to use OpenSSL1.1.0g. The tool uses the library and compiles it in the build file. Unfortunately the tool does not successfully build when my OpenSSL configuration does not explicitly enable `ssl3-methods`. When I configured OpenSSL with: `enable-ssl3-method` the tool successfully compile. I then tried to disable ssl3 so I have:

```
no-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method
```

It also compiles. I do not get the difference between the two. I need the tool not to negotiate TLS with SSLv3 and also not accept it if it is the only supported version by the server.

Can anyone clarify if this configuration ok? what is the difference between the two options? Will they prevent client support for SSLv3?

Unfortunately I can not even test the version by connecting to a SSLv3 server. The tool parse TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 as SSL3, but this is not an issue with me as long as it does not accept handshek with SSLv3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disable-ssl3` (or `no-ssl3`) option will prevent the SSL 3.0 protocol version from ever being **negotiated** in the library. This is [done](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/9829b5ab52cb5f1891fc48262503b7eec32351b3) by default since OpenSSL 1.1.0 (but of course defaults can be changed).

The `enable-ssl3-method` option controls what part of the **code** will be built. If your legacy application links to the `SSLv3_method` function, then this option must be set if you want to use your legacy application unchanged. I believe that even with this option, no SSLv3.0 will be negotiated if disabled before with `disable-ssl3`.

Also note that the `disable-ssl3-method` option implies `disable-ssl3`.

Applications should use `TLS_method` instead of the more specific `SSLv3_method`, `TLSv1_method`, `TLSv1_1_method`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I manually compiled different latest version of openssl package from https://www.openssl.org/source/ using the below command. I understand that sslv3 is disabled using the "Configure" file as mentioned here using "no-ssl" and "no-ssl-method". Still I used below command to disable it.

./config --prefix=/opt/openssl/openssl-$SSLVER --openssldir=/opt/openssl/openssl-$SSLVER  no-shared no-ssl no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method no-ubsan no-unit-test no-weak-ssl-ciphers enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 enable-tls1_2

After compiling, it still shows SSLV3 version support in below command. Can someone please let me know why it is still displayed there and how can I compile openssl so that it will never show SSLV3 support in below output.

```
# ./bin/openssl ciphers -v|grep -i SSLv3
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and no this value in `ciphers -v` **does NOT mean SSLv3 protocol is supported**. It means each listed ciphersuite was _defined_ in SSLv3 but is also supported in later/higher protocols, through 1.2, which _are_ still supported. Also your formatting was unreadable, so I fixed it; please read and follow the help shown when you click the ? icon at the top of the edit window.